# config\app.php getting values from database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm saving laravel app settings in database, but i can't use this trick in `config\app.php`. When i use in models or controllers with`setting('app.name')` or `\setting('app.url')` working. But when i use this in `config\app.php` i'm getting this error;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/SeraEnerji/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234
( ! ) RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/vagrant/SeraEnerji/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  401512  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0252  821816  App\Http\Kernel->handle( )  .../index.php:55
3   0.0459  1270304 App\Http\Kernel->renderException( ) .../Kernel.php:120
4   0.0459  1270304 App\Exceptions\Handler->render( )   .../Kernel.php:326
5   0.0459  1270304 App\Exceptions\Handler->render( )   .../Handler.php:49
6   0.0463  1272856 App\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse( )  .../Handler.php:190
7   0.0467  1279088 App\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException( )  .../Handler.php:293
8   0.0467  1279088 App\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths( )   .../Handler.php:378
9   0.0514  1359464 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::replaceNamespace( )  .../Handler.php:401
10  0.0514  1359840 Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic( )  .../Handler.php:401
```

How can i get values from database for `config\app.php`?
İnfo: I'm followed this guide, https://www.qcode.in/save-laravel-app-settings-in-database/

My table:

```
id  |  name                |    val  
----------------------------------------
1   | app_name             | Site Name
2   | app_description      | Site Description
3   | app_url              | example.com
```

```
app\utils\helpers.php

<?php
if (! function_exists('setting')) {
    function setting($key, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return new \App\Models\Setting\Setting();
        }
        if (is_array($key)) {
            return \App\Models\Setting::set($key[0], $key[1]);
        }
        $value = \App\Models\Setting::get($key);
        return is_null($value) ? value($default) : $value;
    }
}
```

```
app\models\setting.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class Setting extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Add a settings value
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param $val
     * @param string $type
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function add($key, $val, $type = 'string')
    {
        if ( self::has($key) ) {
            return self::set($key, $val, $type);
        }

        return self::create(['name' => $key, 'val' => $val, 'type' => $type]) ? $val : false;
    }

    /**
     * Get a settings value
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param null $default
     * @return bool|int|mixed
     */
    public static function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        if ( self::has($key) ) {
            $setting = self::getAllSettings()->where('name', $key)->first();
            return self::castValue($setting->val, $setting->type);
        }

        return self::getDefaultValue($key, $default);
    }

    /**
     * Set a value for setting
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param $val
     * @param string $type
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function set($key, $val, $type = 'string')
    {
        if ( $setting = self::getAllSettings()->where('name', $key)->first() ) {
            return $setting->update([
                'name' => $key,
                'val' => $val,
                'type' => $type]) ? $val : false;
        }

        return self::add($key, $val, $type);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a setting
     *
     * @param $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function remove($key)
    {
        if( self::has($key) ) {
            return self::whereName($key)->delete();
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check if setting exists
     *
     * @param $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function has($key)
    {
        return (boolean) self::getAllSettings()->whereStrict('name', $key)->count();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules for setting fields
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getValidationRules()
    {
        return self::getDefinedSettingFields()->pluck('rules', 'name')
            ->reject(function ($val) {
                return is_null($val);
            })->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Get the data type of a setting
     *
     * @param $field
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getDataType($field)
    {
        $type  = self::getDefinedSettingFields()
            ->pluck('data', 'name')
            ->get($field);

        return is_null($type) ? 'string' : $type;
    }

    /**
     * Get default value for a setting
     *
     * @param $field
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getDefaultValueForField($field)
    {
        return self::getDefinedSettingFields()
            ->pluck('value', 'name')
            ->get($field);
    }

    /**
     * Get default value from config if no value passed
     *
     * @param $key
     * @param $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    private static function getDefaultValue($key, $default)
    {
        return is_null($default) ? self::getDefaultValueForField($key) : $default;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the settings fields from config
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    private static function getDefinedSettingFields()
    {
        return collect(config('setting_fields'))->pluck('inputs')->flatten(1);
    }

    /**
     * caste value into respective type
     *
     * @param $val
     * @param $castTo
     * @return bool|int
     */
    private static function castValue($val, $castTo)
    {
        switch ($castTo) {
            case 'int':
            case 'integer':
                return intval($val);
                break;

            case 'bool':
            case 'boolean':
                return boolval($val);
                break;

            default:
                return $val;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all the settings
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getAllSettings()
    {
        return Cache::rememberForever('settings.all', function() {
            return self::all();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Flush the cache
     */
    public static function flushCache()
    {
        Cache::forget('settings.all');
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updated(function () {
            self::flushCache();
        });

        static::created(function() {
            self::flushCache();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the settings you want to store in database and how you are retrieving?

Comment: İ'm added other codes.

Comment: database connection occurs when app.php executes, as database connection strings are placed in env file, so if you want to use this before that, there may be something else you need to do.

Comment: Are you able to access all the settings you have stored in database using `setting`?

Comment: Yes i can access in controllers and models. And i only need, app_name and app_url, i'm still using env file for database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found to solution. If there are people who have the same problem with me, the solution I found is as follows.

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Setting;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $settings = Setting::all()->pluck('val', 'name');
        config()->set('settings', $settings);
        Config::set([
            'app.name' => \config('settings.app_name'),
            'app.url' => \config('settings.app_url'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that this is gonna run a `SELECT * FROM settings` on every pageview. You should strongly consider caching this data in some way.

Comment: How can i cache in AppServiceProvider?

Comment: Same way you would anywhere else.